# Delphi 5 TStringList NameValueSeparator

Tags: delphi-5, tstringlist

I have a text file with key value pairs like this

```
user1|password1
user2|password2
user3|password3
```

In delphi 10 I use this function to get the key value

```
function getKeyByName(fileName, key: string) : string;
var
  dataFile : TStringList;
begin
  Result := 'Not Found';
  dataFile := TStringList.Create;
  dataFile.LoadFromFile(fileName);
  dataFile.NameValueSeparator := '|';
  if dataFile.Values[key] <> '' then
    Result := dataFile.Values[key];
  dataFile.Free;
end;
```

For now every thing is worked fine.

I try to use this function with delphi 5, but the property (NameValueSeparator) is not exists.

If I change the separator to (=) and the function to:

```
function getKeyByName(fileName, key: string) : string;
var
  dataFile : TStringList;
begin
  Result := 'Not Found';
  dataFile := TStringList.Create;
  dataFile.LoadFromFile(fileName);
  if dataFile.Values[key] <> '' then
    Result := dataFile.Values[key];
  dataFile.Free;
end;
```

I can get the result, but the separator in my text file is (|).

What should I do to set the separator char (|) for the list?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Would be better to use a proper dictionary

Comment: Is it possible to give me an example please.

Comment: You'd need to use a third party dictionary code. It's not very interesting for us to workaround all the limitations of such an ancient delphi. Have you considered writing some code yourself to do this if you don't want to find a third party library?

Comment: I think I will create a DLL file from delphi 10 and load it in delphi5.

Comment: If you are going to do that you can throw away the string list and use a dictionary.

Comment: As I see I have to do that, but can you help me with a small example please?

Comment: There exists plenty of these, there is documentation. I'm sure websearch will be useful to you.

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Delphi 5 does not have the `NameValueSeparator` property, so you will have to parse the individual strings manually, eg:

```
function getKeyByName(fileName, key: string) : string;
var
  dataFile : TStringList;
  i, j: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  Result := 'Not Found';
  dataFile := TStringList.Create;
  try
    dataFile.LoadFromFile(fileName);
    for i := 0 to dataFile.Count-1 do
    begin
      s := dataFile[i];
      j := Pos('|', s);
      if j = 0 then Continue;
      if Copy(s, 1, j-1) <> key then Continue;
      s := Copy(s, j+1, MaxInt);
      if s <> '' then Result := s;
      Break;
    end;
  finally
    dataFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```